# i make a file.tcl when i execute an error produced

Tags: ns2

```
#Create a simulator object  set ns [new Simulator]
#Open the nam trace file  set nf [open out.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf  #Define a 'finish' procedure   proc finish {} {           global ns nf           $ns flush-trace           #Close the trace file           close $nf           #Execute nam on the trace file           exec nam out.nam &           exit 0   }    # Insert your own code for topology creation   # and agent definitions, etc. here      # Node address is 0   $ns node-config -UmtsNodeType rnc   set rnc [$ns create-Umtsnode]    # Node address is 1   $ns node-config -UmtsNodeType bs \                   -downlinkBW 32kbs \                   -downlinkTTI 10ms \                   -uplinkBW 32kbs \                   -uplinkTTI 10ms \   set bs [$ns create-Umtsnode]   #Iub configuration between RNC and BS   $ns setup-Iub $bs $rnc 622Mbit 622Mbit 15ms 15ms DummyDropTail 000   # Node address for ue1 is 2   $ns node-config -UmtsNodeType ue \                   -baseStation $bs \                   -radioNetworkController $rnc    set ue1 [$ns create-Umtsnode]   # Node address for sgsn0 and ggsn0 is 3 and 4, respectively   set sgsn0 [$ns node]   set ggsn0 [$ns node]   # Node address for node1 is 5   set node1 [$ns node]    $ns duplex-link $node1 $ggsn0 622Mbit 1ms DropTail 1000   $ns duplex-link $ggsn0 $sgsn0 622Mbit 1ms DropTail 1000   $ns duplex-link $sgsn0 $rnc 622Mbit 1ms DropTail 1000    $rnc add-gateway $sgsn0      set rtp_sender [new Agent/RTP]   $ns attach-agent $node1 $rtp_sender      set rtp_receiver [new Agent/RTP]   $ns attach-agent $ue1 $rtp_receiver      # Create a CBR traffic source and attach it to udp0   set cbr0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]   $cbr0 set packetSize_ 500   $cbr0 set interval_ 0.005   $cbr0 attach-agent $rtp_sender   #creation of DCH channel   $ns node-config -llType UMTS/RLC/AM \                   -downlinkBW 64kbs \                   -uplinkBW 64kbs \                   -downlinkTTI 10ms \                   -uplinkTTI 10ms   set dch0 [$ns create-dch $ue1 $rtp_receiver]   #Call the finish procedure after 5 seconds simulation time   $ns at 5.0 "finish"   #Run the simulation   $ns run
```

can any one know about this error 
 invalid command name o3
 while executing 
ns namtrace-all nf 
file .tst.tcl line 6)

Comment: Please format your code so that it's human-readable. Also, please ask a real question.

Answer (score 0):

You may post a clearer code if you want some help.

Anyway, just have a look at the examples given in [0] and try to look for differences between your code and theirs.

Thanks,

Nicolas

[0] http://nile.wpi.edu/NS/